# Siebel script is failing while running for multiple iterations

Tags: performance, loadrunner, siebel

I have recorded the Siebel CRM using the Loadrunner Siebel web protocol.

I have used the Siebel correlation library while recording the script.

The replay is sucessful for a single iterations.

But when we are running for mutiple iterations, the script is only passing the 1st iteration and faling at the subsequent iterations.

The script is passing at the correlated parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_rowid" while running for the 1st iteration.

**Replay extended log(with parameter substitution) for 1st Iteration:**

```
Action.c(437): web_submit_data("start.swe_16") started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op90_rowid" =  "1SIA-5VT8"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_SWECount" =  "6"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op90_1" =  "04757GC1B837DC526"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "Vehicle Admin"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "Vehicle Admin"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "Vehicle Admin"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "SRN_Param" =  "em5VZBI694AirMRd1NSi9fAOUADi9YcdBcPnjccapR4b"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op90_5" =  "Hyundai"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "SiebelTimeStamp" =  "1383655597773"
Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "Vehicle Admin"
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_1 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_2 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_3 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_4 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_5 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_6 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_7 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_8 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_9 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_10 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_11 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_12 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_13 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_14 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_15 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_16 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_17 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_18 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_19 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_20 = SADMIN".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_21 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_22 = Default Organization".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_23 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_24 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_25 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_26 = USD".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_27 = 11/05/2013".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_28 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_29 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_30 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_31 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_32 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_33 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_34 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_35 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_36 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_37 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_38 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_39 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_40 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_41 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_42 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_43 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_44 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_45 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_46 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_47 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_48 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_49 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_50 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_51 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_52 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_53 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_54 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_55 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_56 = ".
Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_rowid = 1-1X7Q9F".
Action.c(437): web_submit_data("start.swe_16") was successful, 4161 body bytes, 293 header bytes    [MsgId: MMSG-26386]
```

**But the script is failing at the correlated parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_rowid" while running for the 2nd iteration.**

**Replay extended log(with parameter substitution) for 2nd Iteration:**
    Action.c(437): web_submit_data("start.swe_16") started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op90_rowid" =  "1SIA-JN6P"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_SWECount" =  "11"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op90_1" =  "0FORDJIKJI890909080"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "1SIA-5VT8"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "1SIA-5VT8"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "1SIA-5VT8"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "SRN_Param" =  "em5VZBI694AirMRd1NSi9fAOUADi9YcdBcPnjccapR4b"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op90_5" =  "Mercedez"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "SiebelTimeStamp" =  "1383655607466"
    Action.c(437): Notify: Parameter Substitution: parameter "Siebel_Star_Array_Op92_rowid" =  "1SIA-5VT8"
    Action.c(437): Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110". Check whether the requested boundaries exist in the response data. Also, if the data you want to save exceeds 99999 bytes, use web_set_max_html_param_len to increase the parameter size    [MsgId: MERR-26377]
    Action.c(437): Notify: Saving Parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110 = ".
    Action.c(437): web_submit_data("start.swe_16") highest severity level was "ERROR", 980 body bytes, 267 header bytes     [MsgId: MMSG-26388]

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Record twice and compare.  You most likely have a piece of dynamic data which is unhandled that you will need to address with manual correlation methods.   Auto correlation libraries are like silver bullets, very very useful when you run into a werewolf.  Otherwise they are just very expensive bullets that you still need to take careful aim with.

- LoadRunner Axiom 1: If auto correlation does not work then use manual correlation.
- LoadRunner Axiom 2: If you don't know how to engage in manual correlation then you should never leverage auto correlation, for when it fails (and it will), you will have no other option than to "blame the tool" instead of addressing the core issue in your code.

Comment: James,Thanks for yor answer.I have done the manual correlation also.But the script is failing for the correlated parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_rowid" during 2nd iteration.Please help.

Comment: That is an autocorrelated item.  Record twice.  Examine the request and find out why it is failing.  Identify the missing or mishandled piece and address it.

Answer (score 0):

Its the common issue in Siebel, it will not work for multiple iterations,

its a correlation issue.

Follow the below steps.
1. Run the script for 2 iterations
2. check each and every value of the correlated values in iteration1 and iteration 2
3. if you see the same value for both the iteration, that is the culprit
4. Do a manual correlation for the culprit value which is same in both iteration.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi,Thanks for yor answer.I have done the manual correlation also.But the script is failing for the correlated parameter "Siebel_Star_Array110_rowid" during 2nd iteration.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Show the script or the workflow of business process.
Is it possible, that your Row_id is empty in 2nd iteration?
Other option: multiple 10 the value in **lr_set_param_len**

My little experience in LR+Siebel gave me one rule: **query record, then pick it.**
In query results You will always have Your row_id.

And option number three:
1)put **web_reg_save_param** before each function with SWE-method changing the rows (PickRecord, SaveRecord etc.).
2)run the script with log-replay option "Extended Log". In Replay Log you will see the Parameters with Your Row_Id. Use these parameters in function-calls that fails.